# Vertical aligning a child element with position absolute and margin auto fails in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to align a child element inside a parent container. 
Below you see a snippet from my code. Just the basics to make it work:

```
// HTML //

<div class="parent">
    <div>Parent</div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>


// CSS //

.parent { position: relative; }

.child {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 60px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: Chrome and IE] Chrome & IE

[image: Firefox] Firefox

[View example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/5977/)

If you view this in Chrome or IE it's aligned in the middle. 
But in Firefox it's not. 
Is this a Firefox bug, or are Chrome and IE doing it wrong?

When you make the child smaller then the parent (in height), it's correctly aligned in the center in Firefox also. Only when it's bigger this issue appears.

Comment: well, you do have conflicting values. you can't have .child be both `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`, unless child is exactly the same height as parent. e.g. You're 1 meter tall. simultaneously put your hands on the ceiling and feet on the floor of a 2 meter tall room... no stretching allowed.

Comment: @MarcB - That's a common technique for vertically centering an absolutely positioned element within a relatively positioned container, assuming the margin is set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bottom attribute from the child and set the top to "-20px". This is tested as working in Firefox DE ^^. You could also -100%, I'd say this would cause problems if the parent height changes, however with a set height on the child if the parent height was varying you would probably have to use a calc.

Comment: I know how to make it work, that's not the problem. I'd like to know what the correct behavior is.

Comment: Well in that case to answer WHY, it is as a comment mentioned top:0 and bottom:0 are conflicting. Someone mentions about vertically aligning but you have set a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a way to fix this so it behaves the same in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

Instead of:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

I tried:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

This seems to work, even in IE9.

[View example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/5992/)